# Import dataset from url and convert text to csv in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am pretty new to Python (using Python3) and read Pandas to import dataset.

I need to import dataset from url - https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission/index.txt 
and convert it to csv file, I am getting some special character in converted csv -> ��

I am download txt file and converting it to csv, is is the right approach?
and converted csv is putting entire text into one column

```
        from urllib.request import urlretrieve

        import pandas as pd
        from pandas import DataFrame

        url = 'https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission/index.txt'

        urlretrieve(url, 'index.txt')


        df = pd.read_csv('index.txt', sep='/t', engine='python', lineterminator='\r\n')
        csv_file = df.to_csv('index.csv', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)
        print(csv_file)
```

after successful import, I have to Extract X as all columns except the first column and Y as first column also.
I'll appreciate your all help.

Comment: how does this work? `df = pd.read_csv('index.txt', sep='\\t', engine='python').dropna()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/leukemia_remission/index.txt'
urlretrieve(url, 'index.txt')

df = pd.read_csv('index.txt', sep='\t',encoding='utf-16')
Y = df[['REMISS']]
X = df.drop(['REMISS'],axis=1)
```

Comment: I have updated with following changes: 
    df = pd.read_csv('index.txt', sep='\\t', engine='python') 
    ab = df.to_csv('index.csv', sep=",", index=None)' 

now output csv file having all the text data ( comma seprated) in single column and rest are coming as blank columns